# Performance issue while fetching Audio

Tags: android, performance, audio, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am fetching a device's audio data in android using the following code

```
public void getSongList()
{
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            Bitmap image = null;
            try
            {
                byte[] art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opt.inSampleSize = 2;
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length, opt);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            mSongModel.add(new SongModel(id,title,artist,image));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

The problem is,it is significantly affecting the startup time.

So any suggestion of performance improvement will be appreciated.
Or,should I use Asynchronous task for this purpose?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using metamediaDataRetriever to get the albumart from the track itself rather than from the media database. In my app New Playlist Manager, I do not use metamediaDataRetriever at all and get albumart using the Glide library

```
                  //  loading album cover using Glide library
            String stralbumId = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM_ID));
            Uri ImageUrl = getAlbumUri(mContext, stralbumId);
            if (ImageUrl != null) {
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(ImageUrl)
                        .into(image);
            }
```

and

```
   public Uri getAlbumUri(Context mContext,String album_id){
    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sArtworkUri, String.valueOf(album_id));
    return imageUri;

}
```

no more manipulating of bytes or Out of Memory errors etc. It does all the heavy lifting.

Add in your app module's build.gradle:

```
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much cor your answer

Comment: so IS THERE ANY NEED TO USE ASYNC TO RETRIEVE THE CURSOR DATA?!

Comment: I use async task to populate my music elements. Put the above in the RecyclerViewCursorAdapter in bindItem(cursor c)

Comment: to be a little clearer, Yes you should use asyncTask to fetch the cursor. presenting of the data takes place in the adapter to which you pass the cursor as illustrated in answer below. Have a look at https://www.blogc.at/2015/10/13/recyclerview-adapters-part-2-recyclerview-cursor-adapter/

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
     @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (loaderID) {
        case LOADER:

            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    dataColumns,
                    selection, selectionArgs,
                    sort_order);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {


    mAdapter = new new_showallTracksAdapter(new_showallTracksFragment.this.getActivity(),c, listener);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    mAdapter.setLayout(currentlayout);
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.Now its all clear to me